# Unix search pattern using egrep

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, grep

Hi friends,

I need to search for two patterns in a file. Ex. *pattern1* and *pattern2* and I want exactly that particular word. Based on the success or failure of this command, I'm going to have two actions using "IF".

example.

`if (condition)`

The condition is evaluating [egrep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep) command for searching two patterns in the file.
The condition should be true `($? = 0)` only if both patterns are found in the file. else it should fail.

But the actual `egrep` command is doing *OR* function between patterns and I want *AND* logic between patterns. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your egrep command and pattern?

Comment: Hi this is my script.
#!/bin/ksh

echo "Enter the START processing period : "
read start

echo "Enter the END processing period : "
read end

if egrep -q "^$start$" example.txt && egrep -q "^$end$" example.txt
then
 echo "VALID processing period"
else
 echo "INVALID processing period"
fi

-- My intention was to use a single egep (as to search for two patterns in a single command) and the pattern as a WORD and not a substring. So i have added ^ and $ symbol at the beginning and at the end of the pattern.

Comment: #!/bin/ksh

    echo "Enter the START processing period : "
    read start

    echo "Enter the END processing period : "
    read end

    if egrep -q "^$start$" example.txt && egrep -q "^$end$" example.txt
    then
    echo "VALID processing period"
    else
    echo "INVALID processing period"
    fi

Comment: Edit your question and insert script in code block. It's completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just connect two greps in your shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

if egrep -q "pattern1" filename && egrep -q "pattern2" filename; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

The `-q` ensures that there is not output from `egrep` (it just returns true if the pattern was found), and the `&&` ensures that `exit 0` is only returned if *both* patterns were found in the file.

Comment: Hi thanks.. But my requirement is to use 'egrep' and searching two patterns in it with AND condition... But here you have suggested to use two grep commands . Can you help in this regard ?

Comment: Please accept and/or upvote one of the answer when you think your question was answered, so that other people know which answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

It's logically vague. If you want to check both patterns in file regardless of if they are in the same line or not, you could do

```
grep 'pattern1' somefile && grep 'pattren2' somefile
```

If you want both patterns to be present in the same line

```
grep 'pattern1' somefile | grep 'pattern2'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. For searching a particular word (NOT as substring) the syntax is to add a '^' at the beginning of the pattern and '$' at its end. That is... grep '^pattern1$' <filename> . I have my pattern as a variable in the script and it should be used as $pattern1.. Can you tell me how to specify that '$' inordr not to confuse with the end '$' we specify within '' ??

Comment: Values withing single-quotes ('$pattern') isn't expanded by shell, so it is as it stands. So your version would be `grep "^$pattern1\$"`. However, two things - 1. word IS a substring, and 2. your pattern will match entire string because `^` is beginning of string and `$` is the ending.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the following worked out for me :

Requirement: searching two different patterns on different lines and take action based on AND opration of the two pattern search.

Code:

```
grep -q "pettern1" file1 && grep -q "pettern2" file1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo "Both patterns are not found"
else
   echo "Both patterns are found"
fi
```

NOTE : both pattens are on different lines in the same file

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -z -q 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1'
```

If both patterns are present in the file it will return true, otherwise false.